# How do I change the default command for `run-python`?

Tags: python, emacs, python-3.x

I'm starting on a Python 3 project, so I'd like to configure Emacs' `run-python` command to use the `python3` interpreter by default.

I don't want to

- change `python` so that it points to `python3` instead of `python2.7` (because that might cause various bad things)
- pass `"python3"` as an argument to the `run-python` command each time I run it (because that sounds annoying)

I've tried setting `python-which-shell` to `"python3"` in my `.emacs`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Emacs 24.3, add to your `.emacs`:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
```

If this doesn't work on an older Emacs with a different Python mode, try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `run-python` <kbd>RET</kbd> to inspect the source for an equivalent variable that can be set.

Comment: I'm using Emacs 23.4.1, where the equivalent variable is `python-command`. Adding `(setq python-command "python3")` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shebang line to specify which version you want to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Will use whichever one the system considers "python"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2
```

Will run the specified version if you have more than one installed.

A friend taught me this when our Ops guy set up a VM with 2.6 and 2.7 installed, and I required 2.7, while the CentOS package manager required 2.6. Saved me a lot of having to go back and make things 2.6-compatible.

Comment: Even if I add this to the top of the file I'm working in, then run the Python repl with `C-c RET`, it uses the Python 2.7 interpreter. To clarify, I'm asking about using a particular interpreter from Emacs' `run-python` command, not from shell.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Ah, that clarifies it a bit. This speed-reading ability is not helping me a bit.